# How to configure subsonic 3.0.0.4 using mysql with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, subsonic, data-access-layer

I downloaded subsonic 3.0.0.4 and i am trying now to configure it to work with mysql and Visual studio 2010.

My project is .net 3.5 and i am creating a data access layer class library to use later in a website.

I can't figure which files i should add to my project and where to edit.

Last step i reached is in this screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see your screenshot as it's blocked here however it sounds like you might need to include the MySQL specific TT templates. Have you configured the other TT templates to use

<#@ include file="MySQL.ttinclude" #>
Instead of
<#@ include file="SQLServer.ttinclude" #>

You can download the MySQL templates from:

http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/tree/master/TemplateProviders/

Comment: your answer is right, thank you while i still have many problems, will try to figure why happening.